# What means value returned by "long = mciSendString()" in MCI

Tags: c#, mci

try to work with MCI and found some sample with code like `long = mciSendString();`
what means this value

try it, my code

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    private static extern long mciSendString(string strCommand,
        StringBuilder strReturn, int iReturnLength, IntPtr hwndCallback);
...
private string MPlayerCommand; // command for MCI usage
private long error;
....
public void play()
    {
        MPlayerCommand = "play MediaFile";
        error = mciSendString(MPlayerCommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
```

return me value like

[image: returned value]

and each time (even if open same file) this value is different - main q - what is this value means???

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 0):

You should read [mciSendString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation regarding the meaning of the returned value. Here's a list of these possible [values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

But in any case, your signature of the mciSendString method is wrong, it returns an Int32 (DWORD) and not an Int64 (long).

I hope this will help you, even though this thread is quite old.